# Check for open, unescaped quotes in a given string

Tags: javascript, regex

A part of the application I'm building allows you to evaluate `bash` commands in an interactive terminal. On enter, the command is run. I'm trying to make it a bit more flexible, and allow for commands spanning multiple lines.

I already check for a trailing backslash, now I'm trying to figure out how to tell if there is an open string. I have not been successful in writing a regex for this, as it should also support escaped quotes.

For example:

```
echo "this is a 
\"very\" cool quote"
```

Comment: what's your RegEx so far? are you looking for `[\s\S]*` instead of `.*` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a regex that matches a string (`subject`) only if it doesn't contain unbalanced (unescaped) quotes, then try the following:

```
/^(?:[^"\\]|\\.|"(?:\\.|[^"\\])*")*$/.test(subject)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^          # Match the start of the string.
(?:        # Match either...
 [^"\\]    #  a character besides quotes or backslash
|          # or
 \\.       #  any escaped character
|          # or
 "         #  a closed string, i. e. one that starts with a quote,
 (?:       #  followed by either
  \\.      #   an escaped character
 |         #  or
  [^"\\]   #   any other character except quote or backslash
 )*        #  any number of times,
 "         #  and a closing quote.
)*         # Repeat as often as needed.
$          # Match the end of the string.
```